# After ads load on my webpage the Waypoint offsets are no longer right

Tags: javascript, jquery-waypoints

Like the title says, I'm currently trying to make a webpage where when you scroll to a certain point it will push the current post in your history.
The problem I've been having is that once the ads load on the page the Waypoint triggers are no longer valid. I know that if I Waypoint.refreshAll() it will fix the problem so maybe theres a jQuery function that I could use that will activate after every single thing on the webpage has been loaded. Or maybe there's a better way to do this than Waypoints? please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a way to make this work I decided to turn to scrollmagic, but if someone has an answer I'd be curious, at first I thought of making a function that would constantly check if the page changed size, and then refresh the Waypoints, but I think that's too expensive in the long run. Or I thought of checking if you hit the top of the articles with a scroll listener but again I still think that's too expensive.